# Scheme - program to count the number of pairs (SICP ex 3.17) - is my solution correct?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, sicp

I need to devise a procedure which returns the number of distinct pairs in any structure. Is my program correct? The solutions I have found online are all quite different.

```
(define (count-pairs x)
  (define (count-cdr x)
    (if (not (pair? x))
        0
        (+ (count-pairs (car x))
           (count-cdr (cdr x)))))
  (if (not (pair? x))
      0
      (+ (count-pairs (car x))
         (count-cdr (cdr x))
         1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the question asks for the number of *distinct* pairs in *any* structure, so we have to be careful and avoid counting more than once the same pair, even if it's in a different place within the structure! Also notice the hint:

> Traverse the structure, maintaining an auxiliary data structure that is used to keep track of which pairs have already been counted

You *have to* keep track of the pairs you've found, and check if they are repeated, your solution completely ignores the hint. This worked for me:

```
(define (count-pairs x)
  (let ((acc '()))
    (define (count lst)
      (cond ((or (not (pair? lst)) (memq lst acc)) 0)
            (else (set! acc (cons lst acc))
                  (+ 1 (count (car lst)) (count (cdr lst))))))
    (count x)))
```

And here are some tests that prove my point:

```
(define l1 (cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 null))))

(define x1 (cons null null))
(define y1 (cons x1 x1))
(define l2 (cons y1 null))

(define x2 (cons 1 (cons 2 null)))
(define l3 (cons x2 x2))

(define x3  (cons null null))
(define y3  (cons x3 x3))
(define l4 (cons y3 y3))

(count-pairs l1)
=> 3
(count-pairs l2)
=> 3
(count-pairs l3)
=> 3
(count-pairs l4)
=> 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is a rather natural approach to this in Scheme.  Although people (notably me) obsess about making processes iterative rather than recursive rather too much (why is stack space so much more valuable than the potentially huge agenda that this code creates?), it is quite nice to write iterative programs for this sort of thing.

This function keeps two lists:

- a list of pairs that it has already seen, so it can know whether it's seen a pair
- an agenda of things it needs to process, onto which it pushes the cdr of new pair it sees, before processing the car.

The process is then to check if the thing it's looking at is both a pair and has not been seen.  If that's true then it adds one to the count and processes the car of the pair, pushing the cdr onto the agenda and the pair as whole onto the seen list.  If that's not true then it either pulls something off the agenda to process, or, if there's no agenda it's finished and the count is the answer.

Note that, in real life, `cp-loop` would be a named `let` which makes the iteration clearer I think.

```lisp
(define (count-pairs thing)
  (define (cp-loop it count agenda seen)
    (cond
      [(and (pair? it) (not (memq it seen)))
       ;; It's a pair, and we have not seen it, so:
       ;; - add one to the count
       ;; - loop on its car
       ;; - pushing its cdr onto the agenda
       ;; - note we've seen it
       (cp-loop (car it)
                (+ count 1)
                (cons (cdr it) agenda)
                (cons it seen))]
      [(not (null? agenda))
       ;; Either it is not a pair, or we've seen it
       ;; But there is more to do, so:
       ;; - pick the first agenda item & try that
       (cp-loop (first agenda)
                count
                (rest agenda)
                seen)]
      [else
       ;; it's not a pair or we have seen it
       ;; and there is no agenda: we are done
       count]))
  (cp-loop thing 0 '() '()))
```

And now:

```
> (define o1 '(1 . (2 . (3 . ()))))
> o1
'(1 2 3)
> (count-pairs o1)
3
> (define o2 '(1 . (2 . (3 . (4 . 5)))))
> o2
'(1 2 3 4 . 5)
> (count-pairs o2)
4
> (define o3 (cons o1 o1))
> (count-pairs o3)
4
> o3
'((1 2 3) 1 2 3)
> (count-pairs '((1 2 3) 1 2 3))
7
```